# After installing mainline kernel 3.4.3, why can't I build the AMD graphics binary module?

Tags: drivers, kernel, ati, fglrx

I recently updated my Ubuntu 12.04 kernel to 3.4.3-generic, and now my ATI/AMD drivers will not install correctly. AMD Catalyst Control Center is there, and I can open it fine, but it only shows 2D graphics as being enabled. My graphics card is the Radeon HD 7770, and was working completely fine on my older kernel (2.5.xx). I get the following output when attempting to install the latest drivers from AMD (the error is a little more than half way through it):

```
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx.
(Reading database ... 261454 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fglrx (from fglrx_8.961-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
restore of system environment completed
Error! There are no instances of module: fglrx
8.961 located in the DKMS tree.
Errors during DKMS module removal
Uninstall fglrx driver complete.
For detailed log of uninstall, please see /etc/ati/fglrx-uninstall.log
System must be rebooted to avoid system instability and potential data loss.
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-amdcccle.
Unpacking fglrx-amdcccle (from fglrx-amdcccle_8.961-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-dev.
Unpacking fglrx-dev (from fglrx-dev_8.961-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up fglrx (2:8.961-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl32.icd because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl32.icd (of link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken.
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl32.icd because associated file /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl32.icd (of link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) doesn't exist.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Loading new fglrx-8.961 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.4.3-030403-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.4.3-030403-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.4.3-030403-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.4.3-030403-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/make.log for more information.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Setting up fglrx-amdcccle (2:8.961-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up fglrx-dev (2:8.961-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.4.3-030403-generic
```

Running fglrxinfo in the command line returns the following:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  138 (ATIFGLEXTENSION)
Minor opcode of failed request:  66 ()
Serial number of failed request:  13
Current serial number in output stream:  13
```

Basically, it looks like the installer is failing when attempting to build for kernel 3.4.3... is there anything I can do about this, or do I have to wait for AMD to release updated drivers?

Lastly, here is the output recorded in /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/make.log:

```
DKMS make.log for fglrx-8.961 for kernel 3.4.3-030403-generic (x86_64)
Tue Jun 19 23:40:17 CDT 2012
AMD kernel module generator version 2.1
doing Makefile based build for kernel 2.6.x and higher
rm -rf *.c *.h *.o *.ko *.a .??* *.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/3.4.3-030403-generic/build SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.4.3-030403-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.o
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c: In function ‘kasInitExecutionLevels’:
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:4157:5: error: ‘cpu_possible_map’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:4157:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:4157:5: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.4.3-030403-generic'
make: *** [kmod_build] Error 2
build failed with return value 2
```

Anyone know what if there is anything that I can do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of no stable kernel API.

Anyway, sounds like it'll be fixed in Catalyst 12.5, or if you need a workaround:
http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/tumbleweed/475575-warning-kernel-3-4-amd-catalyst-12-4-not-compatible.html